# Нахождение номера недели по дате java

Tags: java, алгоритм, datetime

Есть график на две недели , то есть с 1 сентября у нас начинается первая неделя , потом следующая вторая, а потом следующая опять первая. Подскажите как средствами java реализовать алгоритм который будет определять какая сейчас неделя по графику получая на вход текущую дату.
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
    Date start = null;

    try {
        start = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/09/2019"); //получим дату 1-го сентября 2019
    } catch (ParseException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    long delay = System.currentTimeMillis() - start.getTime(); //получим разницу (в мс) между сегодня и 1-ым сентября
    long week = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; //кол-во миллисекунд в одной неделе
    delay %= week * 2; //найдем остаток от деления разницы на две недели

    if (delay <= week) System.out.println("First week"); //если разница меньше либо равна одной неделе, то это первая неделя
    else System.out.println("Second week"); //иначе вторая
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользоваться [классом Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), получить номер недели и посмотреть, является ли он четным или нечетным.

```
public Boolean IsOdd(Date date){
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    return calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) % 2 != 0;
}
```

Comment: А если недель будет не 2, а больше 4?

Comment: @wcobalt то на этот случай у меня в коде присутствует деление по модулю на 2, поэтому хоть все пять. Или вы о чем-то другом? В любом случае это можно подогнать под нужную задачу, главное ее правильно описать.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю получив 1 неделю месяца, при графике в пять недель она может быть что первой, что второй ...что пятой. И обычное деление по модулю тут не поможет

Comment: Честно говоря, я не вижу причины почему мой код неправильный, т.к. если в вопросе сказано что с 1 сентября первая - так оно у меня и работает. Можете объяснить, подробнее?

Comment: @wcobalt, это может быть оформление рабочего расписания на учебный год. Во многих учебных заведениях занятия чередуются раз в 2 недели (например, в первую идут лекции, а вторую семинары). Для этого придумали чередовать учебные недели и называть их «четная» и «нечетная» соответственно. Тогда **с 1 сентября и до ближайшего воскресенья**  будет нечетная. Если 1 сентября выпадет на четверг, то в этой неделе будет 4 дня только. А с понедельника начнется следующая «четная» неделя. У вас же я так понимаю ровные отрезки по 7 дней без учета текущего дня недели.

Comment: Пожалуй, я согласен. Я это не предусмотрел так как в вопросе это явно не указано, указано как раз явно обратное. (В моем ВУЗе недели вообще от 1 до 4 нумеруются.)

Comment: @wcobalt, ну... подробности знает только автор, без уточнения оба подхода допускаются.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.WEEKS;

public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(isFirstWeek(LocalDate.of(2019, 9, 10)));
    }    
    public static boolean isFirstWeek (LocalDate date) {
        return date.getMonthValue()>=9 ? 
                WEEKS.between(date.withMonth(9).withDayOfMonth(1), date)%2==0 : 
                WEEKS.between(date.withMonth(9).withDayOfMonth(1).minusYears(1), date)%2==0;
    }    
}
```

Я так понимаю, что речь идет об расписании на учебный год. Это вариант всегда считает недели как 1 сентября + 7 дней, учитывая, что учебный год не равен календарному, т.е., к примеру, 5 сентября 2019 и 5 марта 2020 - это разные календарные годы, но один учебный. Все это корректно с точки зрения временного промежутка. Вместе с тем, если Вам нужно учитывать дни недели, то это неверное решение. Например, 1 сентября 2019 года это воскресенье. Следовательно, 1 неделю следует отсчитывать с понедельника 2 сентября. Однако, если бы 1 сентября пришлось, например, на четверг, то первая неделя состояла бы только из 4 дней с четверга по воскресенье включительно. 
Если Вам нужно именно это , то метод следует несколько изменить:

```
public static boolean isFirstWeek (LocalDate date) {        
    final LocalDate firstMonday = date.getMonthValue()>=9 ? 
            date.withMonth(9).withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(date.getDayOfWeek().getValue()-1) : 
            date.withMonth(9).withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(date.getDayOfWeek().getValue()-1).minusYears(1);          
    return firstMonday.minusDays(firstMonday.getDayOfWeek().getValue()-1).isBefore(firstMonday) ? 
            WEEKS.between(firstMonday, date)%2==0 : WEEKS.between(firstMonday, date)%2!=0;
}
```